# nethogs shows 0 KB although I have traffic

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, network-adapter

I am running a network related program that performs TLS handshakes with many hosts. I ant to monitor the network traffic so I used `nethogs`. It shows 0 KB.
NetHogs version 0.8.5-2

```
PID USER     PROGRAM                    DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
  ? root     unknown TCP                            0.000       0.000 KB/sec

  TOTAL                                                 0.000       0.000 KB/sec
```

I have previously run this program and `nethogs` was showing me information about the network traffic. What is the problem? How to see the ongoing/outgoing traffic? Are there alternative tools?

I use Ubuntu 18.04.

EDIT:
The command I entered:

```
sudo nethogs
```

I also tried with the adapter name that I obtain using `ifconfig`:

```
sudo nethogs enx9cebe8b0d86a
```